# Xcode 8 "Lost connection to iPhone" on iOS 10 Device crashes (memory leaks?)

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

My app is running on iPhone 7 without any problems, but on iPhone 5 the app crashes and Xcode displays an error "Lost connection to iPhone". There is no debug output. I think, it's because too much memory consumption, but I don't know how to use instruments. Can someone tell me if there is something going wrong and what I can do? The app crashes after loading AnnotationViews for MKMapView. This is the output in Instruments until the app crashes:
[image: Instruments output]

Comment: Look at top of colum. 657MB? Oh yeah, that's too much memory all right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) Do you have a hint for me, how I can find the piece of code that is responsible for this? Are there any tricks in instruments, how to do that?

Comment: I think your suspicion that it has something to do with your annotation views is probably right. It certainly seems to have something to do with drawing views. Are you dequeuing your annotation views correctly? Are you overburdening your map view with too many annotations at once?

Comment: @RalfHundewadt same issue. did you find code from instrument?